# How to use cache calls in Joomla 4

Tags: cache, joomla-4.x

From the [documentation](https://docs.joomla.org/Using_caching_to_speed_up_your_code) I use this part to store a large chunk of data

```
if (empty($families)) {
  $cache = Factory::getCache();
  $families = $cache->call( array( 'JFormFieldFamily', 'getFamilyList' ) );
}
```

Working perfectly on my Joomla 3.9.6, however my extension in Joomla 4 throws this

```
Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback,
class 'Joomla\CMS\Cache\Cache' does not have a method 'call' in
site\libraries\src\Cache\CacheController.php on line 74
```

Looking into the [documentation](https://api.joomla.org/cms-3/classes/Joomla.CMS.Cache.Cache.html) for `Joomla\CMS\Cache\Cache`

```
$families = $cache->call( array( 'JFormFieldFamily', 'getFamilyList' ) );
```

becomes

```
$families = $cache->get( array( 'JFormFieldFamily', 'getFamilyList' ) );
```

and works properly on Joomla 3.9/4.

Do I need to use `$cache->store()` method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `call` method has been marked as removed for Joomla 4.0, as it's simply a wrapper for `get()`.

You don't need to manually store the cache as this is done within the `get()` method:

https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/blob/4.0-dev/libraries/src/Cache/Controller/CallbackController.php#L139

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, perhaps this should be reported to the Joomla dev team.

Comment: You're welcome. I've submited an issue on the Issue Tracker

Comment: @thednp Apparently `@deprecated 4.0` means it will be removed in 4.0. Rather bad terminology in my opinion but oh well.